# Why is it not possible to declare an array with a constant expression?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, std

I have a two dimensional `std::array`,

```
std::array<std::array<string, n_height>, n_width> data_able;
```

`n_height` and `n_width` are constant variables, which I don't know their values for different `dataTables`, and the only possible way to get their values is using a function call:

```
const size_t n_height = dcmI_image->get_height();
const size_t n_width = dcm_image->get_width();
```

But that is not possible, and this is what I get as an error:

```
error: the value of ‘n_height’ is not usable in a constant expression
 ‘n_height’ was not initialized with a constant expression
```

The same is for nWidth of course.

Comment: They not only need to be constant, their values must be known at compile time. That is functions `getHeight` and `getWidth` must be `constexpr` and evaluated at compile time.

Comment: "constant expression" (and corresponding keyword `constexpr`) dictate *compile-time* expressions

Comment: @VTT I changed the declaration of my const variable to `constexpr size_t nHieght = dcmImage->getHeight();` but I get this error: `call to non-constexpr function ‘long unsigned int DicomImage::getHeight() const’ `
So, I guess the function definition must be a constant expression.

Comment: [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is the container of choice for runtime-length arrays. if your width/height aren't known at compile time, use this.

Comment: @0x499602D2 thanks man, I was just thinking abut it, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size of an array must be a constant expression such as `constexpr` or a literal, not just `const`.  If the size is known at compile time, you can simply change your `const` to `constexpr`.  If the size is not known at compile time, you cannot directly use `std::array`.

Comment: So, as a conclusion, I can not use  `std::array` with those conditions.

Comment: @ZSmain -- right: if the size is not known at compile time you cannot create a C-style array or an `std::array`. You can use `std::vector`.